# How to filter out shortcode when displaying the_excerpt() in the loop?

Tags: functions, filters, excerpt, regex

I'm using `the_excerpt()` in my template loop to display post excerpt on the front page.

It's currently displaying unwanted shortcode directly on the front page

eg.

`[box]post content[/box]`

`[alert]post content[/alert]`

How can I filter out these shortcode only while keeping the actual content?

Comment: From where you are getting this unwanted shortcodes ?

Comment: The shortcode was originally from another Wordpress framework.  I'm now working on a customized theme.  It's in the development stage, and I don't want to manually remove all the shortcode in hundreds of posts just to do the testing.  When `the_excerpt()` is called, it displays the shortcode directly as plain text (since the new theme doesn't support the parsing of the shortcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'strip_shortcodes', 20 );
```

or try this edit

```
echo strip_shortcodes( get_the_excerpt() );
```

if shortcode is not register with wordpress function add_shortcode

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcodes_in_excerpt', 20 );

function remove_shortcodes_in_excerpt( $content){
    $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
    $tagnames = array('box', 'alert');  // add shortcode tag name [box]content[/box] tagname = box
    $content = do_shortcodes_in_html_tags( $content, true, $tagnames );

    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex( $tagnames );
    $content = preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/", 'strip_shortcode_tag', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: added this to `functions.php` and used `echo get_the_excerpt()` in my template, not working.

Comment: edit answer try or condition

Comment: The second edit doesn't work, the shortcode, eg. `[box]the content[/box]` is still there.  Plus, it's changing the read more link into plain text.

Comment: can you check backend edit post  what is in excerpt field there.

Comment: the excerpt field is empty.  i let the system extract excerpt from the content, that's where the shortcode taking place.

Comment: show your excerpt content using this $post->post_excerpt

Comment: another answer suggested the same method of $post->post_excerpt and I need to use regular expression to manually strip the shortcode one by one.  I still can't figure out a way to strip off all the shortcode cases.  Can it be written into a function in functions.php so I can call it from different template loops?

Comment: I have question what is shortcode working in single post ? Mean shortcode not give anything output in excerpt or full content.

Comment: I described in the comment on my original question earlier.  The shorcodes were from a Wordpress framework.  I'm developing a new theme which do not rely on the framework.  In the meantime I can't manage to remove hundreds of shortcodes just for testing purpose.

Comment: strip_shortcodes only work when shortcode is register using add_shortcode function so now i update answer which shortcode do you want to pass a new shortcode name in tagnames array

Comment: It works!!  One question, does 20 have any particular impact?

Answer (score 1):

```php
function wpsesess_ddecode_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
    return strip_shortcodes( $excerpt );
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpsesess_ddecode_excerpt' );
```

**EDIT** Can you please post this in functions.php and let me know?

Comment: Doesn't work, tried switch to `echo get_the_excerpt()` too.  Could it be that after disabling the framework, the shortcode is no longer active/registered, thus the strip_shortcodes won't work?  Is it possible to simply strip `[anything]the content[/anything]` whenever there's a pairing bracket of tags?

Comment: Let's check the edited version

Comment: The new version still doesn't work.  Tried both `the_excerpt()` and `echo get_the_excerpt()`

Comment: use this...   add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');

Comment: Adding the two filters still doesn't help.  I tried the two filters by themselves, and also tested them together with the function in your answer.  I've also tried removing `the_excerpt()` and `echo get_the_excerpt()`, the post page is not showing anything, so the excerpt was properly called, just can't filter out the shortcode.  Could it be any code execution priority issue?

Comment: can you post out your front page code in pastebin?

Comment: See these two links for index.php and content-index.php, http://pastebin.com/uVbqjwdt and http://pastebin.com/XdurEwzE

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
$excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
echo $excerpt;
```

Or:

```
$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
$excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $excerpt);
echo $excerpt;
```

Comment: I placed the code in my template file.  The first one shows the exact same excerpt with shortcode in place.  The second one gave me blank screen.  I replaced the 3rd time of the first code to `echo preg_replace('/\[box\]|\[\/box\]/', '', $excerpt);` to manually strip off the `box` shortcode.  Which does the trick but not a full solution.  I have excerpt in my search result, category, tag, and latest post pages.  I would like to have it done in functions.php so I can re-use it.  Also need to apply to generic shortcode instead manually applying it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your new theme doesn't register the shortcodes they're regarded as plain text. Any attempt at filtering is useless, because as far as WordPress is concerned they aren't shortcodes.

The easiest way to solve this is to register the shortcodes in your new theme and hook them to an action that does nothing besides removing the shortcode.